# Inline code not compiling inside an OnClientClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, inline-code

I'm trying this code inside a `asp:hyppelink` inside a repeater.

```
OnClientClick='openURL( "<%# Eval("UrlPagamento")%>", "<%# Eval("IdPedido")%>")'>
```

and the outcome after compilling is this:

```
<a class="btnPequeno" onclientclick="openURL( &quot;<%# Eval(&quot;UrlPagamento&quot;)%>&quot;, &quot;<%# Eval(&quot;IdPedido&quot;)%>&quot;)" href="#">Pagar</a>
```

I tried to change the symbols **"** and **'** but then I just got a syntax error.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind all the string elements inside the databinding expression and escape the `'` with `&#39;`

```
OnClientClick='<%# "openURL(&#39;" + Eval("UrlPagamento") + "&#39;, &#39;" + Eval("IdPedido") + "&#39;)" %>'
```